# nHibernate Collections issue ( check your mapping file for property type mismatches)

Tags: nhibernate

I'm getting the following error:
Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet to type 'Iesi.Collections.Generic.SortedSet.

Invalid mapping information specified for type [Type], check your mapping file for property type mismatches".

Here's my set definition:

```
<set name="ProcessTrackerDetails" lazy="true" access="field.camelcase-underscore" 
                sort="natural" cascade="all" inverse="true">
  <key column="ProcessTrackerDetailsID"/>
  <one-to-many class="ProcessTrackerDetail"></one-to-many>
</set>
```

And heres the code:

```
private Iesi.Collections.Generic.SortedSet<ProcessTrackerDetail> _processTrackerDetails = new SortedSet<ProcessTrackerDetail>();
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NHibernate requires interfaces. Try to use `ISet<ProcessTrackerDetail>` instead of `SortedSet<ProcessTrackerDetail>`

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean to try to instantiate that interface (Doesn't work)... Or if you mean use a Set instead of a sorted set (Doesn't work either, I need a sorted set)...

There's probably something fundamental I'm missing here.

Comment: You need to use interfaces in classes instead of classes. Interfaces is required for nhibernate to track down changes made to the collections.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to define _processTrackerDetails using the ISet interface.

```
private ISet<ProcessTrackerDetail> _processTrackerDetails = 
    new SortedSet<ProcessTrackerDetail>();
```

You can still assign it to a SortedSet, but I am not sure that it does much when lazy loaded as NHibernate will use it's ISet implementation to do the lazy loading. The sort="natural" in your mapping should take care of the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the 'Set' relation type (unique set of items, NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet) then you can define your mapping with System.Collections.Generic.ICollection and use System.Collections.Generic.HashSet.

I'm using Castle ActiveRecord and this is the code I am using:

```
// In the Collections entity mapping
    [HasAndBelongsToMany(typeof(Region),
    Table = "CollectionRegionAssociation", ColumnKey = "CollectionId", ColumnRef = "RegionId", RelationType = RelationType.Set)]
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Region> Regions { get; set; }

// Creating and saving a new object
    var c = new Collection(); // my own entity
    c.Regions = new System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<Region>();
    c.Regions.Add(new Region() { ... });
    c.Save();
```